# Forwarding packets from eth1 to eth0

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I have a linux box with two interfaces (eth1 and eth0). I have a device connected to eth1 and a PC connected to eth0. The following are their IP addresses:

eth1: 10.75.0.1    netmask 255.255.0.0

eth0: 10.76.0.1    netmask 255.255.0.0

Device on eth1: 10.75.255.210

PC on eth0: 10.76.0.3

My routing table currently looks like this

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.75.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
10.76.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I have a program on the PC that needs to connect to the device on eth1. The device on eth1 is broadcasting a message on port 53103. I want to forward those packets to eth0 so that they can be seen by the program on the PC. I basically want to set my iptable rules so that I enable a two way communication between the program on the PC (eth0) and the device on eth1. Port used by the program is also 53103.

I have tried the following but I don't see the packets on eth0 using tcpdump:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53103 -i eth1 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.76.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: "_The device on eth1 is broadcasting a message on port 53103._" Broadcasts are confined to a single network.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for pointing that out. Can I change the destination address of the broadcast message to a specific address instead of 255.255.255.255 as a workaround?

Comment: You use unicast, or you enable multicast routing and use multicast. Broadcasting is the old way (IPv6 does not even have broadcast), and it interrupts _every_ host on the network, even those not interested, such as routers, printers, etc. Multicast is the more modern way to send to a group, and it can be thought of as a targeted broadcast, interrupting only the hosts that subscribe to the broadcast group.

Comment: Can I change the destination address of the broadcast packets to the PC ip address?

Comment: Possibly, but bridging different networks can cause other problems, too. You really want to eliminate anything using broadcast, which is completely out of date for modern networks.

Comment: Yes, I realised bridging will not be the best solution. I just edited my last comment to another question

Comment: That would be NAT, but the problem with that is you cannot reply that way because the source address of a reply would be translated to the broadcast address, and broadcast or multicast addresses cannot be source addresses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103858/discussion-between-gebre-and-ron-maupin).